# Swift - how to create correct sectionForSectionIndexTitle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, indexing

I have a section index that contains full alphabet - however, sections in my table contains only a few letters (e.g. C, F, N, U).

I would like to modify sectionForSectionIndexTitle to properly show right sections when sliding finger over section index. I'm still not sure how to do it using sections.append...

Thank you for help.

This is how my code looks like:

**Section.swift**

```
struct Section
{
    var heading : String
    var items : [String]

    init(title: String, objects : [String]) {

        heading = title
        items = objects
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
func updateSections(index : Int) {

    switch index {

    case 0:
        sections.append(Section(title: "C", objects: ["Czech Republic"]))
        sections.append(Section(title: "F", objects: ["France"]))
        sections.append(Section(title: "N", objects: ["Norway"]))
        sections.append(Section(title: "U", objects: ["USA"]))

    default: break
    }

    tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
}

let arrIndexSection = ["A","B","C","D", "E", "F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    if segmentedControlOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        return arrIndexSection
    } else {
        return [""]
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    let temp = arrIndexSection as NSArray
    return temp.indexOfObject(title)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section = sections[section]
    return section.items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section].heading
}
```

Comment: where do you call updateSections() ?

Comment: On many places (e.g. segmented control or UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection). The code above is just the most relevant part related to the question.

Comment: what is your question? how can i help?

Answer (score 2):

try following code in  your project :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    var tempIndex:Int = 0
    for str in arrIndexSection {
        if str == title {
            return tempIndex
        }
        tempIndex += 1
    }
    return 0
}
```